# How to set custom marker icon size in static google map?

Tags: google-maps-static-api

How to set custom marker icon size in static google map in website? I want to set size 100 * 130.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you also can add your custom marker with your desirable size

```
       int height = 100;
        int width = 130;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.marker);
        Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
        Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
```

Comment: Can you please explain in php?

Comment: I am creating a static map in php , there i cannot create a marker with size 100*140.When i am adding the size in static map, it display the normal marker icon.

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/schools_maps.png%7Csize:103x136%7C40.702147,-74.015794%7C40.711614,-74.012318%7C40.718217,-73.998284&key=AIzaSyDIJ9XX2ZvRKCJcFRrl-lRanEtFUow4piM